# Can't fire keypress event when press delete key

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyevent

I'm finding that the delete key doesn't fire the `keypress` event in Chrome, while other keys work. The problem doesn't occur in Firefox, just in Chrome, why? Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
     console.log(e);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `keydown` or `keyup` instead, it captures the delete key (as well as others that keypress doesn't, see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
     console.log(e);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

`keypress` event for (Del, End, Home,etc..) is not fired in  **IE, Chrome and safari**.. it only works in **firefox.**.

so  you can use the `keyup` or `keydown` event because the `keypress` event is intented for real (printable) characters. `"keydown"` is handled at a lower level so it will capture all non-printing keys like DEL, End, etc